# MySQL for SQL Server DBAs

Tags: sql-server, mysql

I've been tasked with taking over the administration of a MySQL installation (running on Red Hat Linux) that will become fairly critical to our business in the near future.

I was wondering if anyone could recommend some resources in regards to administering MySQL for DBAs already experienced with other relational database (SQL Server and some Oracle in my case). Specifically I'm looking for information around disaster recovery as well as high availability to start with, but I do want to get well rounded with the entire system.

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A great resource about MySQL is [Percona's blogs](http://www.percona.com/about-us/blogs/), you'll find information about pretty every configuration options on it. You **must** read the official documentation related to High Availablity too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-ha-scalability/en/index.html

Another good thing to do is for you to buy the book from O'Reilly named [MySQL CookBook](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596001452), it's very well structured and will introduce you to the way MySQL works.

One thing you should not underestimate is the OS your MySQL instances will run on (*NIX I hope for your sake), if you don't have any experience on it you should begin learning what impact the different filesystems (**and** their options) can have on MySQL performances before you even try to setup your server.

Don't be afraid, from my experience SQL Server is much more intricate (I'd even said touchy) concerning settings and functionalities than MySQL.

Comment: +1, this answer is my answer too. Percona, especially the MySQL Performance Blog. Then, play with it. Conventional wisdom with InnoDB is to use mysqldump with --single-transaction --all-databases. If you have a big enough system running, Percona has a free hot-dump backup system.

Comment: @Autocracy - I think the common parlance there is "hot-copy" or "hot-backup"

Comment: @danlefree You are correct.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess RTFM is the best place to start.  I also check out the Percona blog and the MySQL CookBook as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you're a book nerd like me, get Paul DuBois' "MySQL" (Developer's Library). I've found it to be the only MySQL book I've needed on my shelf for a couple years now (sitting next to the several dozen I have on SQL Server).

[http://www.amazon.com/gp/product/0672329387?ie=UTF8](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672329387)